# Run multiple instances of apache with PHP5

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, opensuse

I am attempting to setup a Dell Poweredge R720 server with OpenSUSE 13.1.

I need to run multiple instances of apache (Either 1 install multiple instances or multiple installs with multiple instances). All the googling I do for setting this up comes up with results pertaining to running multiple versions of php on multiple apache instances, which is not what I want.

Does anyone know whether this is feasible or not, and if so, if they have any handy sites/words of wisdom as to how to accomplish this?

Comment: Why not Virtual hosts?

Comment: @Pants I need to have completely separate MySQL databases, and the ability to turn the servers completely off without affecting the other servers.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need multiple instances of apache (or PHP for that matter) to have separate MySQL databases in the backend.

If you actually need to *completely* turn off the web server instances then I suggest that you virtualize your environment and either run apache/PHP in containers or in separate virtual machines.

Note that this will require one IP address per webserver/container/VM. Are you really sure that you can't do this with a shared frontend (nginx for example), and then have separate PHP-FPM pools in the background for each customer/site?

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see a situation that you would need to install apache multiple times, there are other solutions.

Have you considered creating containers that meet your specifications and deploying them when needed.

https://www.docker.com/

You could use virtual machines, but I think docker will do exactly what you need with less overhead.